# Where should I be doing my aggregation/calculations while using the MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I've just started to learn to code and wanted to ask what the best practice is when totalling up some numbers and displaying it while using the MERN stack. Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

Context:

- I'm building a website where I can add my bike ride details through a React form and store it into MongoDB. Each ride consists of **date, time, totalDistance, duration, maxSpeed**.
- I would like a summary page where I show the **totalDistance this week/month, total duration this week/month, average speed this week/month.**

Ask:

- For the summary page totals above, where should I be calculating the totals? Should I be computing the totals in React by pulling all the database information? Should/can I do it in Node? Or should I create a collection in Mongo where I keep track of the totals so that I don't have to compute the totals each time the page is loaded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is possible to calculate the totals within a MongoDB Aggregation query - on the database server. You will run the code from the NodeJS application. You can refer the MongoDB documentation for Aggregation pipeline stage $group and $count to start with. That said, you can do the calculations anywhere within the application - on the server or the client. It is generally efficient to perform calculations and summaries on the database server (if you can) and get the results in the application and post them to the user interface.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, ability to aggregate, will read up on it.